# Organizing multi library cmake target with gtests

Tags: cmake, googletest, project-organization

I am starting to introduce googletests to our multi-library production codebase and  I would like some advice on how to organize better my tests.

We have many internal libraries that we compile as a grand library that executables link against.
The structure let's say is something like:

```
├──LIB_A
|   ├──CMakeLists.txt
|   ├──src/
|   └──include/
├──LIB_B
|   ├──CMakeLists.txt
|   ├──src/
|   └──include/
...
├──LIB_Z
|   ├──CMakeLists.txt
|   ├──src/
|   └──include/
└──CMakeLists.txt
```

The last CMakeLists will add_subdirectory() the libraries and produce the Grand Library.

In this structure I would like to introduce tests. Most tests I am thinking of, are to test each library rather than the whole thing. I have been advised by a colleague that tests should be introduced to the Grand Library level and not inside each library. To make it graphic, what would be best?

A:

```
├──LIB_A
|   ├──CMakeLists.txt
|   ├──src/
|   ├──include/
|   └──tests/
├──LIB_B
|   ├──CMakeLists.txt
|   ├──src/
|   ├──include/
|   └──tests/
...
├──LIB_Z
|   ├──CMakeLists.txt
|   ├──src/
|   ├──include/
|   └──tests/
└──CMakeLists.txt
```

OR B:

```
├──LIB_A
|   ├──CMakeLists.txt
|   ├──src/
|   └──include/
├──LIB_B
|   ├──CMakeLists.txt
|   ├──src/
|   └──include/
...
├──LIB_Z
|   ├──CMakeLists.txt
|   ├──src/
|   └──include/
├──tests/
└──CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: "I have been advised by a colleague that tests should be introduced to the Grand Library level and not inside each library. To make it graphic, what would be best?" - Both approaches work. If you currently have no preferences, then take any approach and start coding.

Comment: There are unit tests and integration tests. These are different set of tests.

Answer (score 1):

> what would be best?

Both.

```
├──LIB_A
|   ├──tests/  <- unit tests of LIB_A components
               \- and integration tests of LIB_A with dependent components

├──tests/      <- integration tests between all components
               \- functional tests of the whole system
```